# How to return the response of 2 REST APIS to a 3rd REST API using Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, pom.xml

I am new to Apache Camel and I wanted to integrate or merge results of 2 API GET Requests and route their responses to a 3rd API.

1st API - http://localhost:8080/students/Student1 (GET method Returns {"id":"1","name":xyz"})
2nd API - http://localhost:8081/students/Student1 (GET method Returns {"id":"1","subject":"maths"})
3rd API - http://localhost:8082/students/combine (GET method should produce
{"id":"1","subject":"maths","name":"xyz"}

**What I actually want to do is hit the 3rd API with a GET request so that it can implicitly call API1 and API2 and return output as:
{"id":"1","subject":"maths","name":"xyz"}**

This is the code I have written.

CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
JacksonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(Output.class);

```
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/students/Student1")
            .to("direct:merge)

             from("jetty:http://localhost:8081/students/Student1")
            .to("direct:merge")
             
             from("direct:merge")
            .to("jetty:http://localhost:8082/students/combine")
        }
    });
    context.start();
}
```

}

Comment: if you are sending request to the 3rd API, shouldn't it be a post request?

Comment: I actually want to hit the 3rd API with a GET method that performs a GET request to the 2 APIs and combines their results.

Comment: If there is a solution using POST request, that would also work as well.

Comment: does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610820/apache-camel-to-aggregate-multiple-rest-service-responses

Comment: Yes it does help a lot. I have seen this answer before. However, I am getting a "cannot bind to localhost:8082" error. The port is not in use anywhere else. Any idea on that?